# how to update unique field for multiple entries in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple Django model similar to this:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    test_field = LowerCaseCharField(max_length=20, null=False,
                                verbose_name='Test Field')
    other_test_field = LowerCaseCharField(max_length=20, null=False, unique=True,
                                verbose_name='Other Test Field')
```

Notice that other_test_field is a unique field. Now I also have some data stored that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        test_field: "object1",
        other_test_field: "test1"
    },
    {
        test_field: "object2",
        other_test_field: "test2"
    }
]
```

All I'm trying to do now is switch the other_test_field fields in these two objects, so that the first object has "test2" and the second object has "test1" for other_test_field. How do I accomplish that while preserving the uniqueness? Ultimately I'm trying to update data in bulk, not just swapping two fields.

Anything that updates data in serial is going to hit an IntegrityError due to unique constraint violation, and I don't know a good way to remove the unique constraint temporarily, for this one operation, before adding it back. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of changes are we talking about - are those very regular and could be done using F() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions - though this might not help at all.

Comment: Also: are you executing your update inside `transaction.atomic()`? If not, can you try with it?

Comment: I tried with transaction.atomic but it still hits the unique constraint error at the database level. I think that's because the transaction cannot be committed as its constructed, since the database doesn't know how to handle updating one field at a time while preserving uniqueness at the end.

Comment: the change may happen pretty regularly, and results in potentially multiple objects switching unique field values. I'm considering finding a different way of establishing uniqueness for this field, one that allows duplicates temporarily while objects are being updated.